# Trying to set up python demo for App engine + pubsub with flask - gcloud doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

forked from the basic demo app as part of google app engine demo, I added the following:

```
@app.route('/eventq')
def eventq():
  from gcloud import pubsub
  client = pubsub.Client()
  topic = client.topic('eventqueue')
  topic.publish('app accessed', attr1='value1', attr2='value2')
  return 'gggggrrrr'
```

The app fails when the route is accessed with gcloud not supported.

Things I have tried:

adding gcloud to /lib which then says I don't have google.protobuf, which I also installed and that didn't work either.

pip install on the machine

adding gcloud to app.yaml, which then said the package wasn't supported.

The code works when running locally on my machine but doesn't when running on Google App Engine.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial, guide or git repo you are using?  Can you also provide the exact stack trace of the error?  Knowing with, we can attempt to do this ourselves and identify more precisely where the problem may lie.

Comment: I eventually decided to drop Google Cloud entirely for this project and do it with AWS.

If I remember correctly I read through these docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/apis#app-engine-python-api

and the app is forked from the example app provided.

also:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-python/tree/master/appengine-push